# Send Cloud Message to specific flutter app user from Node cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am running a cloud scheduler with firebase functions and would like to send the specific user a notification when something in the cloud using node js has completed, I researched about cloud messaging but it send it to everyone, I don't want that, how can I achieve what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send notifications to a specific app instance by targeting the FCM device registration tokens.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices